# Splitting of a word to create a past tense or verb

Tags: grammar, etymology

So, I was looking at the word "backup" recently. This is the only word I know of that splits the word to indicate an action("I'm backing it up now.") or for past tense("When was it last backed up?"). Are there any other words that do this? If not, why is this word so special in it's use?

Comment: Actually, *backup* is the noun and *back up* is the verb.  If you want words that behave the same way (are combined in the noun but split up in the verb), try *login*, *logout*, *comeback*, *pickup*, *breakdown*, and many more.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that most or all of these started as p-verbs (p=preposition or particle or phrasal or whatever your particular grammatical confession calls them), and the nouns are derivative.

Answer (score 1):

There are several compound words which properly serve as nouns but have also been used (some would say incorrectly) as verbs.

- **Backup** was *back up* (*backed up*, *backing up*).
- **Login** was *log in* (*logged in*, *logging in*; also, *logon*, *logout*, *logoff*).
- **Signin** was *sign in* (*signed in*, *signing in*; also, *signon*, *signout*, and *signoff*).

After writing these out, I saw Peter Shor's comment which added:

- **Comeback** was *come back* (*came back*, *coming back*).
- **Pickup** was *pick up* (*picked up*, *picking up*).
- **Breakdown** was *break down* (*broke down*, *breaking down*).

Answer (score 1):

Backup was not one word. It started off as back-up.

Similar words

- Back-up.
  Backing up, backed up.
  Wrong: Backuping, backupped.
- Layout.
  Laying out, laid out.
  Wrong: layouting, or layouted.
- Sign-in.
  Signing in, signed in.
  Wrong: sign-inning, sign-inned.
- Set-up.
  Setting up, set up.
  Wrong: setupping.